# The Lagrange inversion formula (the proof from Wikipedia)

Tags: power-series, combinatorics

English Wikipedia gives a very short proof of the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula), using the formal residue. However, I don't understand the second equality,
$$k \, \mathrm{Res} (g^n \, X^{-k-1}) = k \, \mathrm{Res} (X^n \, f^{-k-1} \, f').$$
It apparently should follow from $f (g(x)) = g (f(x)) = x$ and from the ["calculus rules" for formal residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_residue), but I don't see how.

Could anybody help? Many thanks.

Comment: It’s an instance of rule iv.

Comment: Literally got stuck on this exact point, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Btw, it's me who wrote that. I adapted from Richard Stanley's book "Enumerative Combinatorics" (vol 2, Ch 5, Thm 5.4.2), a reading that I warmly suggest for a better insight.